# TypeORM queryBuilder : orderBy relation count

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have a basic query to retrieve `course` entities that have a manyToMany relation with `student` as `registered_students`. I also would like to map a `students_count` property which I managed to achieve through `loadRelationCountAndMap`.

What I can't figure out is how to `orderBy` that `students_count` value that is not a column of the `course` entity :

```js
return await this.courseRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('course')
      .where('course.teacherId = :teacherId', { teacherId: teacher.id })
      .leftJoin('course.registered_students', 'student')
      .addSelect('student.firstName')
      .addSelect('student.lastName')
      .loadRelationCountAndMap(
        'course.students_count',
        'course.registered_students',
        'students_count',
      )
      .getMany();
```

I understand I can't simply add something `.orderBy('course.students_count', 'DESC')` as it doesn't refer to a column but I can't find a simple way for that, even though it can appear trivial....

Answer (score 0):

This issue came up for me, my first solution was something like this, appended to the queryBuilder call return statement:

```
.then(
([entities,count]) => {
entities.sort(yourSortFunctionHere);
return entities;
})
```

A simple in memory sort. Not pretty, but delivers desired functionality.

It is possible also inside the queryBuilder with:

```
.addSelect('CAST(COUNT(student.id) AS INT)', 'studentcount');
```

And making sure 'studentcount' is the string value passed into your .orderBy call. You will also need to add an index for the student id on courses, or else the query will be very slow.